# Who is the Cackler?

Tags: deadlands-classic, deadlands-reloaded

Recently, Pinnacle has been [promoting a Kickstarter](https://www.peginc.com/dead-men-walking-stone-and-the-cackler-together/) involving Stone and "The Cackler". Here's a quick snippet:

> The third Deadlands Plot Point Campaign is on its way, featuring everyone’s favorite hero-killer, Stone! But we’re going to bump up the “dead factor” and combine him with the long-awaited tale of the Weird West’s oldest and most mysterious Harrowed—teased since the beginning of Deadlands in 1996—the Cackler!

I've heard of Stone (he's in the Marshal's section of the Player's Guide for one), but apparently the Cackler lives up to his epithet as "the most mysterious Harrowed" because I've never heard of him, despite having read a fair amount of *Deadlands Classic* and *Deadlands Reloaded*. (And references to him must have been really subtle if he was teased since 1996).

Since he's described in that writeup as "the oldest Harrowed", I presume that he's the one described in the entry for Stone in *Deadlands Reloaded Marshal's Handbook*.

> Stone is the first Harrowed of the Reckoning. That's not to say he's the *first* Harrowed—that dubious distinction lies with some else (and we ain't sharing yet, partner).

However, it's not clear if that's the Cackler or not since oldest does not necessarily mean first (the first might have been killed off for good).

So who is the Cackler and what book or books has he been in before this upcoming graphic novel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure about as far back as 1996, but the Cackler is officially named and introduced in the 2000 supplement The Black Circle: Unholy Alliance.

See the pdf reprint here:

http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/1361/Deadlands-Classic-The-Black-Circle?it=1

Quoting from the teaser text there:

> Marshals will get their first hints of a major new force in the Weird West: the Cackler!

Here is a summary of what is said about the Cackler in this supplement.

**Spoiler alert!** (hover text below)

> The Cackler is an ancient lich from England, a kind of English counterpart to Stone. He pre-dates the Reckoning, though his power has benefited from it. He is a surviving son of an ancient sorceress, the sorceress also being an ancestor of the Whateley Clan. In the Black Circle supplement, the Cackler has got Mina (who encountered him on a visit to England) and the Wichita Witches tracking down the descendent who is foretold to carry his mother's spirit. The supplement is pretty clear however that Marshals should not introduce the Cackler directly—he should rather be a force behind the scenes, as he has some big evil purpose in the future of the setting.

Comment: @Thunderforge, this is a blast from the past! Glad you accepted my answer :-)

Answer (score -3):

He's basically Mordred with some of the Arthurian mythological stuff swapped out with Atlantean mythology.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please check out the [tour] and the [help] to get an idea of how it works. Your answer could use some fleshing out, otherwise it's likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: As Miniman said, try to expand your answers a little bit, that way we can rely on your answer and learn a bit more.